# Use a custom Log4J appender when running spark in AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, log4j, amazon-emr, appender

I'm trying to execute spark submit in AWS EMR to execute a simple project that uses a custom log4j appender that I wrote.
Im able to pass my log4j properties by providing the following configuration in cluster software settings:

```
[{
    "classification": "spark-log4j",
    "properties": {
        "log4j.appender.S": "CustomLog4JAppender",
        "log4j.rootLogger": "DEBUG,S"
    }
}
```

]

But when I'm running the cluster step I'm getting:
**log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [CustomLog4JAppender].  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CustomLog4JAppender**
in the cluster stderr.

The jar that I'm executing is located in S3 and it contains the Main class, my appender class and all the dependencies.

I'm executing the cluster using: command-runner.jar
and executing the following command:
**spark-submit --deploy-mode client --class Main s3://{path_to_jar}.jar**

So a few questions here:

1. Which component in the cluster loads the log4j logger and properties? does it happen in the master node? in the core node?
2. What can I do in order to solve this issue? How should I execute it differently? how to make it recognize my custom appender class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also developed a custom `log4j` appender class and used it as follows in my `log4j.properties` file with no problem:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, defaultLog
log4j.appender.defaultLog=com.my.package.CustomLog4jFileAppender
```

so my guess is that this line of code `"log4j.appender.S": "CustomLog4JAppender"` is not enough to locate your custom appender, and you probably need to give the location of your custom appender class. Try this:

```
"log4j.appender.S": "com.yourPackage.CustomLog4JAppender",
```

Comment: Actually in my case the appender is in the same package as the main program and therefore my properties are correct. I was able to solve the issue by adding a Bootstrap action that copies the jar with the appender to **/usr/lib/spark/jars/**. What I don't understand is why it didn't see the appender when it was part of the application jar.